# How to grant comment right on column of a table to a database user in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to give right to a database user wherein the user can add/edit comments on any column of a table .
I wrote this command , but it is giving error **missing or invalid privilege** , please help with the correct query , I don't have to give right on all tables to the user that is why didn't use this command
`GRANT COMMENT ON ANY TABLE TO DILIP` .

```
GRANT COMMENT ON COLUMN STN_CODE.STATION_LIST TO DILIP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that.

- owner can comment anything they want on their own tables/columns
- other users require `comment any table` privilege

If you don't want to grant that privilege, then create a **stored procedure** which will be used by those users. Something like this: I'll add comment only to `loc` column in the `dept` table.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_comm (par_comment in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'comment on column dept.loc is ' || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(par_comment);
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's test it: column `loc` doesn't have any comments:

```
SQL> select * from user_col_comments where table_name = 'DEPT';

TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAM COMMENTS
--------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
DEPT            DEPTNO
DEPT            DNAME
DEPT            LOC

SQL> exec p_comm('department location');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Any comments now?

```
SQL> select * from user_col_comments where table_name = 'DEPT';

TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAM COMMENTS
--------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
DEPT            DEPTNO
DEPT            DNAME
DEPT            LOC        department location

SQL>
```

Looks OK.